# How do I properly implement a cancellable, long-running thread in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, autoresetevent

I want to have a method that runs some processing that lasts at most a second, sleeps for 5 minutes, and repeats.  I also want a user to be able to break out of the sleep and quit gracefully.  I want this to run throughout the day without consuming too many system resources.  What is the best design pattern for this?

Here's my first attempt:

- I use a thread to wait and to do the processing.  I'm unsure if I should use a thread, a thread pool thread, or a task.  I don't think it should be a task though because there are no asynchronous IO operations involved.  I also don't think I should use a Timer because I want to be able to stop the thread gracefully without waiting for the next interval.
- I use AutoResetEvents to signal between the two threads.  This allows the inner code to run either when the time is up or when a user wants to quit.
- I apologize if this question is a duplicate.  If so, I can't find it.

Here's my code:

```
var areCanContinue = new AutoResetEvent(false);
bool shouldContinue = true;

var thread = new Thread(obj =>
{
    while (true)
    {
        areCanContinue.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
        if (shouldContinue)
        {
            Process();
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
});
thread.Start();

string response;
do
{
    Console.WriteLine("Press 'q' to quit");
    response = Console.ReadLine();
} while (response != "q");

shouldContinue = false;
areCanContinue.Set();
```

Comment: are you familiar with timer?

Comment: @Media, I mentioned a Timer in my second point.  I don't think it's a fit here because I want to be able to cancel the process in between intervals.  I don't know how to do that with a Timer.

Comment: @user2023861 To cancel the timer, just dispose it. My answer supposed that you wanted to run some cleanup before exiting, but otherwise using directly a timer is a much better solution

Comment: I suggest you to put a button and then stop the timer, see [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjFzbKc_r3TAhXHbxQKHRu9CfQQFggiMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.codeproject.com%2FQuestions%2F252805%2FHow-to-pause-resume-the-timer-in-WPF&usg=AFQjCNEQU4DsJe-g6rCwf4hmevdAf6OoLA&sig2=LyOEKiNjyYICsz2Ux5z9wA&cad=rja)

Comment: @KevinGosse, I read this about the Timer.Dispose() call `Note that callbacks can occur after the Dispose() method overload has been called` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer(v=vs.110).aspx  I think that's ok in my scenario.  If not, I'd go with your Task solution.

Comment: @user2023861 If you call `Dispose` just when the timer is about to tick, the callback may still be called once slightly afterwards because it has already been scheduled on the threadpool. This shouldn't be an issue in most cases

Comment: @user2023861 CancellationTokenSource/Tasks is your friend in this case, instead of using Signalling for this. IMHO

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tasks aren't necessarily for I/O bound operations. In fact, this is a good use-case for `Task.Delay` (which internally wraps a timer):

```
public static async Task ProcessAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    try
    {
        while (true)
        {
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5), cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);

            Process();
        }
    }
    catch (TaskCanceledException)
    {
        // Cancellation requested, do whatever cleanup you need then exit gracefully
    }
}
```

Then to use it:

```
var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

var task = ProcessAsync(cancellationTokenSource.Token);

string response;
do
{
    Console.WriteLine("Press 'q' to quit");
    response = Console.ReadLine();
} while (response != "q");

cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();

task.Wait(); // Wait for the task to finish
```

---

Depending on your requirements, you can also directly use a timer:

```
var timer = new Timer(_ => Process(), null, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));

string response;
do
{
    Console.WriteLine("Press 'q' to quit");
    response = Console.ReadLine();
} while (response != "q");

timer.Dispose(); // Stop the timer
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Operation op = new Operation();
        var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        Task.Factory.StartNew( async () => await op.LongRunningApplication(tokenSource.Token));
        while(true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("PRINT STOP for Cancellation...");
            var str = Console.ReadLine();
            if(string.Compare(str, "Stop", true) == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Cancellation Requested...");
                tokenSource.Cancel();
                Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)).Wait(); // Making Sure that It stops gracefully since this is console app
                break;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Completed");
    }
}

public class Operation
{
    public async Task LongRunningApplication(CancellationToken token)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Starting long Running application....");
        while (true)
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000);   // Your Operation
            Console.WriteLine("Wating...");
            for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
            {
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));  // Wait For 5 Mins (10 sec , 30 intervals)
                if (token != null && token.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Stopping GraceFully..");
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```